GAS Filter() not returning expected results
In the following [data][1]:
|First Name|Last Name|Email | |--|---|----------| |A |a |A@email.com| |B |b |B@email.com| |C |c |C@email.com| |D |d |D@email.com| |E |e |E@email.com|
, I'm having an issue using filter() (ln 19 below) to extract only the emails of the users whose first and last name match the selected users from the last col and row of [eList][2]:
|Some other column|Name | |--|--| ||a,A, b,B| ||c,C| ||C,c, D,d, E,e|
Right now filter() is returning all emails. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?
Here is the function:
//Extracts emails from data of selected users function
getEmailAddresses(e) {
  // Get the responses from the form.
  const responses = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET_ID").getSheetByName("Form Responses 2");
  // Extract the selected names from the checkboxes.
  const eList = responses.getRange(responses.getLastRow(),2,1, 1).getValues();
  Logger.log("eList\n" + eList);

  // Get the spreadsheet and sheet
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET_ID");
  const shet = ss.getSheetByName('ECI');

  const data = shet.getRange(2, 1, shet.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues();

  Logger.log("Data\n" + data);

  // Filter the data based on selected names and extract email addresses.
  const emailAddresses = data.map((row) => row[2] || false).filter(Boolean);  // Filter() is not returning the emails of the selected users only, returns all emails
  Logger.log("Emails\n" + emailAddresses);

  // Return the email addresses as a comma-separated string.
  return emailAddresses.join(','); }

// Populates Name in the Form
onOpen(e) function popFormList() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID').getSheetByName("ECI");
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

  // Populates values for eList
  var siteValues = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2),
          values = siteValues.getValues();

  values.sort();
  Logger.log(values);

  /* Populates eList with Names from ECI sheet */
  var siteItem = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX)
                   .filter(function (siteItem) {
    return siteItem.getTitle() === "Name";
  })[0].asCheckboxItem();
  siteItem.setChoiceValues(values);

} // Runs when form is submitted with selected users to extract the emails of users for comms
function main(e) {
  var formResponses = e.response,
      itemResponses = formResponses.getItemResponses(),
               body = "",
             emails = "";

  for (x = 0; x < itemResponses.length; x++) {
    if (itemResponses[x].getResponse() === "") {
      continue;
    }
    else {
      body += itemResponses[x].getItem().getTitle() + ": " + itemResponses[x].getResponse() + "\n";
    }   }   emails = getEmailAddresses(e);   subject = "ECI Request"   Logger.log(emails);   Logger.log(body);

  try {
    // GmailApp.sendEmail(emails, subject, body, { noReply: true});   }   catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Error: There was a problem please see below\n' + e);   } }

[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/fkcIID6t.png   [2]: https://i.sstatic.net/GPfrcJoQ.png

Please avoid images and share your data as a formatted text table.

Please provide minimal reproducible example.

The filter doesn't use eList. It just filters out the empty strings. BTW, there's no need for || false because Boolean() has the same effect.

Please don't edit your original code to include possible answers! Leave it as it was; otherwise it would be very confusing for other people seeing this later.

Right now this line:
const emailAddresses = data.map((row) => row[2] || false).filter(Boolean);

is just filtering out empty values. You can see that eList doesn't appear in the expression at all.
You can try changing it to this:
const selectedNames = eList.split(', ').map(item => item.split(','));
const emailAddresses = data.filter(row => {
  return selectedNames.some(fullName => {
    return fullName[0] === row[0] && fullName[1] === row[1] ||
           fullName[1] === row[0] && fullName[0] === row[1];
    });
}).map((row) => row[2]);

For that to work, you should also modify the following line:
// Extract the selected names from the checkboxes.
const eList = responses.getRange(responses.getLastRow(),2,1, 1).getValues();

to this:
const eList = responses.getRange(responses.getLastRow(),2,1, 1).getValue();

What changed? The last s, so the method returns a string instead of a 2D array.
EDIT - Previously, I had suggested the following code:
const selectedNames = eList.split(', ').map(item => item.split(','));
const emailAddresses = data.filter(row =>
                                   selectedNames.includes(row.slice(0, 2)) ||
                                   selectedNames.includes(row.slice(0, 2).reverse()))
                           .map((row) => row[2]);

That doesn't work, of course: I fell victim to the good old passed by reference pitfall.

Thank you for you help! I given these changes a go and returning a blank array. Any recommendation?

Thank you for your continued help! I've tried your suggestions and still returning a blank array. Here is the markup I'm using but getting an error updating question to include eList and data as a table
eList
|Name       |
|--|
|C,c D,d E,e|
data
|First Name|Last Name|Email      |
|--|---|----------|
|A         |a        |A@email.com|
|B         |b        |B@email.com|
|C         |c        |C@email.com|
|D         |d        |D@email.com|
|E         |e        |E@email.com|

I'm getting an error when I try to add the tables to my original question. Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.
Not sure what I'm doing wrong here I'm adding tables not code.

please share what you've discovered

That works! Thank you so much!

ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION
In the example, it seems that the format of the names in the form submission would look like first_name1,last_name1, first_name2,last_name2, first_name3, last_name3.
If that's the case, you may use this method, which gets the names as first,last, adds them to become [ 'first_name1,last_name1', 'first_name2,last_name2', 'first_name3,last_name3' ] and separates them as [ 'first_name1', 'last_name1', 'first_name2', 'last_name2', 'first_name2', 'last_name3' ] to be used in the filtering of data.
This is the modified version script:
function getEmailAddresses() {
  const responses = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET_ID").getSheetByName("Form Responses 2");
  const vl = responses.getRange(responses.getLastRow(), 2, 1, 1).getValues();
  const eList = vl[0][0].split(", ").flatMap(e => e.split(','));
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET_ID");
  const shet = ss.getSheetByName('ECI');
  const data = shet.getRange(2, 1, shet.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues();
  const emailAddresses = data.filter((r) => eList.includes(r[0]) || eList.includes(r[1])).map((r) => r[2]);
  return emailAddresses;
}


Note: I removed the event object (e) from the function since it wasn't in use.

OUTPUT

UPDATE
For users that may have the same first and last names, the script can be modified to:
function getEmailAddresses() {
  const responses = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET_ID").getSheetByName("Form Responses 2");
  const vl = responses.getRange(responses.getLastRow(), 2, 1, 1).getValues();
  const eList = vl[0][0].split(", ").map(e => e.replace(/,/g, " "));
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET_ID");
  const shet = ss.getSheetByName('ECI');
  const data = shet.getRange(2, 1, shet.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues();
  const emailAddresses = data.filter(r => eList.includes(`${r[0]} ${r[1]}`)).map(r => r[2]);
  return emailAddresses;
}

The sample sheet for the Form Responses looks like this:

The sample sheet for ECI looks like this:

OUTPUT

REFERENCES

String.prototype.split()
Array.prototype.flatMap()
Array.prototype.includes()
String.prototype.replace()


Let me know if you have any questions, and I'll be happy to help in any way I can!

Thank you @Saddles I'm going to give this approach a try!

Kindly check the eList screenshot of the post @user27425627. The answer is based on what was provided by the OP, and the form response wouldn't show as John Smith, Jane Doe, Jane Smith, John Doe like what you provided since it'll show as John,Smith, Jane,Doe, Jane,Smith, John,Doe. Testing that on the script I answered works as expected, so I'm unsure why it was downvoted.

My point is that, unless there's something I'm not understanding, your code checks if a row's first name is included in the list of selected names, or if a row's surname is included in the list of selected surnames. Even if you change the || to a &&, it wouldn't necessarily check that the first name and the surname both belong to the same person. Testing it on the OP's data turned out fine because his data (a A, b B, etc) contains exclusively distinct names and family names.

I understand that, and it can easily be addressed. That's the reason why there's an Edit option when answering in Stack Overflow. This is simply a starting point, an Alternative Solution, since the only reason I started working on this was because the initial answer posted was producing an empty output.

You seriously expect the OP's real data to be A | a | a@email.com? It's not a far-fetched situation; having two people with the same name or surname is very probable with enough data.

No, that was an oversight on my end. I simply forgot at the time of my answer since, I will now reiterate, the only reason I started working on this was because the initial answer posted was producing an empty output. Thank you for pointing out my error, and I've now changed my answer to also accommodate that. Just so you know, I did not downvote your answer since I don't do that in general. This conversation has reached a point where we're not finding common ground and would prefer to end this discussion.
